# Use a TList<TCust> across multiple forms

Tags: delphi

My situation is the following:

I have three forms A, B, C. Form A creates both B and C.

I have a TList of custom types that is created on form A and I want to access it from both forms B and C.

My question is, how can I pass this list to forms B and C so that they can access it directly, not each make their copy of?

Comment: Call a function and pass the list as a parameter. Since it is a reference type no copies are made and everybody will reference the same single instance.

Answer (score 0):

Forms B and C can use elements from unit A module if it is declared in `uses` clause (if A `uses` B and C, then place it in `implementation` section of B and C)

But usually the best solution is creation of new common unit with constants and variables shared by other units.

Comment: Is "module" simply a very unusual way of saying "unit"?

Comment: @Andreas Rejbrand  Yes ;) But seems I wrongly understand the question sense.

Answer (score 0):

First declare your list in FormA under the `Public` section:

```
type
  TFormA = class(TForm)
    ...
  private
    { Private-Deklarationen }
  public
    { Public-Deklarationen }
    myList: TList<TCust>;
  end;
```

Don't forget to create it at some point. E.g. under the `FormCreate` method:

```
procedure TFormA.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  myList := TList<TCust>.Create();
end;
```

If you now try to access your list from `FormB` delphi marks it as an error:

```
procedure TFormB.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  FormA.myList
end;
```

Now just try to compile your application. Delphi detects that you want to access another Form and ask, if you want to add it to the uses list:

> Form 'FormB' references form 'FormA' declared in unit 'Unit1' which is
>   not in your USES list. Do you wish to add it?

Click on yes. Now you can access your list from formB like so:

```
procedure TFormB.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var cust: TCust;
begin
  cust := TCust.Create;
  cust.foo := true;
  FormA.myList.Add(cust);
end;
```

**But as MBo already mentioned, it is always better to use a common `unit` for elements that you want to access from different units.**